# Automatically change database connection when creating new queries in SQL Management Studio

Tags: application-settings, ssms

In SQL Management Studio, you can query a database table by right clicking it in the object explorer and selecting 'Select XX Rows'. A window opens showing the query and results. The query includes the database and scheme names. This action does not affect the selected database connection in the toolbar's dropdown list.

I use this as a starting point for manually writing queries, and it's quicker to just query the tables. So I regularly change the current database connection to the database I just created the query for.

Is there a way to make the database connection in the toolbar's dropdown list automatically change to the database where you start a query in the object explorer?

Comment: Add a USE command to the top of your query: USE MyDatabase; GO https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx

Comment: That's an alternative to the issue. It would work if there's a way to have a USE command automatically inserted when you start a new query.

Comment: If that's all you want, just right click the database and do a new query and the toolbar will automatically point there.

Comment: @Steve, thanks, I wasn't aware of this. Maybe I got a bit stuck in old habits. Although it's nice to start new queries with a select statement already prepared by SQL Management Studio, I'd accept your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved since the release of SSMS 2016.